# Customize x axis label in react-apexcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am using react-apexcharts .I have daily financial data for one year but I want show alternate month name on x axis.

```
xaxis: {

   labels: {
       show: true,
       formatter: function (val: any) {
          return dayjs(val).format("MMM");
       }
   }
}
```

This code shows all month on x axis.

How can I display alternate month name on x axis on the chart?

The image has given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To display the month name on x axis of chart. You have to change your formatter function like this

```
    const options = {
    xaxis: {
      labels: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (val) {
          const months = [
            'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
          ];
          const index = months.indexOf(val);
          // Return month name for alternate months
          return index % 2 === 0 ? val : '';
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Himanshu . I have post  another query related to x axis in apex chart.